# Nativescript PhotoSlider Extension / Plugin

Tags: slider, photo, nativescript

Is there any plugin or extension for smooth photoslider in nativescript? I tried using swipe direction but I want a smooth sliding effect on photos. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want a horizontal slider where the user can slide the images from the side?

If so, a simple ScrollView will do.

```
<Page>
 <ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
   <Image src="~/image1.png" />
   <Image src="~/image2.png" />
   <Image src="~/image3.png" />
   <Image src="~/image4.png" />
 </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

Also see the documentation of the ScrollView: https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/scroll-view/HOW-TO.html

Comment: yey! it works :D I also used <StackLayout> above the images.

Comment: Another thing, how can I center the image once I scroll to another image?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/scrollview-7e1541bdfde3 same problem with this. I tried using swipe but sometimes, swipe fails. hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gesture for this process

```
import { SwipeGestureEventData } from "ui/gestures";
export class XXX{
public direction: number;
private images:any[] = ["image url", "image url","image url","image url"];
public current_image;
private image_lenght;
private current_image_count=0;

constructor() {
    this.image_lenght = this.images.length;
    this.current_image = this.images[this.current_image_count];
}

private onSwipe(args: SwipeGestureEventData) {
      direction = args.direction;
    /*left to right direction = 1
    right to left direction = 2
    top to bottom direction = 8
    bottom to top direction = 4*/


    switch (this.direction) {
        case 1:
            if(this.current_image_count != 0)
                this.current_image_count --;
            break;

        case 2:
            if(this.current_image_count < (this.image_lenght) -1)
                this.current_image_count ++;
            break;

        case 4:
            // code...
            break;

        case 8:
            // code.
            break;


        default:
            // code...
            break;
    }

    this.current_image = this.images[this.current_image_count];
  }
}
```

for more information about gesture in Nativescript angular [refer here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/gestures.html)

Comment: That is very cool, but is there a way to put an animation (slide effect) as well during the image change?